# On a page refresh, my app gives me a TypeError: uid null when using firebase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

can somebody can give me a hint as to what's wrong with how I pull in `auth` into my react hook.

It's clearly a problem in the way that I structure my app and pass the `auth` object through it.

**It works fine and retrieves details from the auth however when the page is refreshed, it gives this error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

if (!auth) {
18 |     console.log("error") 19 | } else {
20 |  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid; | ^  21 |  var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid); 22 |     console.log(docRef) 23 |     docRef.get().then((doc) => {
```

**Here is my React Hook (minus the jsx)**

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";

import "./Profile.scss";
import ListingWidget from "../listing/listingWidget/ListingWidget";
import TabSelector from "./TabSelector/TabSelector";
import TradePileWidget from "../listing/tradePileWidget/TradePileWidget";
import SoldItemWidget from "../listing/soldItemWidget/SoldItemWidget";

import {
  db,
  auth
} from "../../firebase.js";

function Profile() {
  const [view, setView] = useState("listing");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [lastname, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [bio, setBio] = useState("");
  const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
        if (!auth) {
          console.log("error")
        } else {
          const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
          var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
          console.log(docRef)
          docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                  setUsername(doc.data().username)
                  setName(doc.data().name)
                  setLastName(doc.data().surname)
                  setBio(doc.data().bio)
                } else {
                  {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                  });
              }
            },
            []
        );
```

So clearly it seems that its trying to read the auth before it's actually loaded, therefore throwing this error.

Does anybody have the best way to pull it in with React to avoid these mismatched loading times?

Cheers!

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/mghedt/on_a_page_refresh_my_app_gives_me_a_typeerror_uid/

Answer (score 0):

I also posted on reddits firebase subreddit and got an answer, the fully working useEffect now looks like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authObj) => {
            unsub();
            if (authObj) {
                setLoading(true);
                const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
                var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
                console.log(docRef)
                docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        setUsername(doc.data().username)
                        setName(doc.data().name)
                        setLastName(doc.data().surname)
                        setBio(doc.data().bio)
                        setLoading(false);
                    } else {
                        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                        console.log("No such document!");
                        setLoading(false);
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                    setLoading(false);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("not logged in");
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

[LINK TO THREAD](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/mghedt/on_a_page_refresh_my_app_gives_me_a_typeerror_uid/)

Check my post above for the original answer ^ :)